# Why do I get ModuleNotFoundError for import cupy?

Tags: python, numpy, cupy

I installed cupy using `pip install cupy-cuda90`. The installation went successfully (after installing MSVC 2017) and `pip list` shows cupy-cuda90.

When I type `import cupy` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-1-329ec5cf1bc8>", line 1, in <module>
import cupy

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cupy'
```

I am on Windows 10 (1607), CUDA 9.0 is installed, and CUDA_PATH & CUDA_PATH_V9_0 point to the right directory.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python installed ? Are you sure that you installed cupy with the same version of python that executed the code?

Comment: Yes, that was the solution. Tee PATH pointed to another python installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.

Eventhough I was starting pip from a specific win python installation, there was another python interpreter installed, which was set in the PATH environment variable. So pip.exe simply used the other python interpreter and installed CuPy there.